# Is it possible to combine REST and Non REST actions and resources from a Non REST partial form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, action, scaffold

I need a separate index/view from a scaffold generated table I’ve created. In this view, I have about half of the original scaffold columns, with the intention of a user being able to edit and update two of them. I created a non scaffold controller to generate this view. So, my questions:

1). Is it possible to combine scaffold and non scaffold resources in the non scaffold partial form?

2). Can I use the edit action and partial from the non scaffold controller with update going to the scaffold table?
I suppose in production, this would likely be some sort of authorization system?, but for now, I just want to find out the possibilities. My view/index in the non scaffold controller works, but of course the edit button does nothing. Am I missing something? For now, I’m using Rails 3.0 on Windows 7 if that makes any difference.

Routing in Partial:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller=> "ravs", :method=> "get", :action=> "edit", :class=>    "_dec") %>

    <div >
    <%= submit_tag(:controller=> "achvrs", :method=> "put", :action=> "update") %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

This is my routes.rb:

```
    Effcnt::Application.routes.draw do
    get "ravs/index"
    get "ravs/edit"
    get "ravs/_dec"
    resources :achvrs
```

This is the edit action in my non scaffold controller:

```
    def edit
    @achvr = Achvr.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Comment: I haven't looked carefully, but I don't think there's ever a case where you want to render a partial as a stand-alone page.  A partial is just supposed to be a kind of reusable view "function".  Let Rails do the work of assembling the page (starting from the layout, and then the specific view and any of its partials, or theirs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code works.  since according to rails API (from rails2.3.x to 3.2), the "submit_tag" doesn't have the options your provided (

```
<%= submit_tag(:controller=> "achvrs", :method=> "put", :action=> "update") %>
```

), what this tag supports are :

```
:confirm => 'question?' - This will add a JavaScript confirm prompt with the question specified. If the user accepts, the form is processed normally, otherwise no action is taken.
:disabled - If true, the user will not be able to use this input.
:disable_with - Value of this parameter will be used as the value for a disabled version of the submit button when the form is submitted.
Any other key creates standard HTML options for the tag.
```

and also, I don't think your implement code make sense, a form could be submit only to 1 target (some_controller#some_action), however it seems that you want to submit a form to 2 actions at 1 time?

so, I think you had better write your code in Rails' MVC's way:  combine the code you want to run into 1 action, e.g.:

```
def the_action_your_form_submitted_to 
    # previously it was called in your RESTful action 
    do_task_no.1   
    # previously it was called in your non-RESTful action
    do_task_no.2   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to be able to, let's say, edit 2 columns of a record in 1 view.

Is the functionality like this?:

1. You visit `ravs#index`
2. `ravs#index` lists all the Achvr records
3. You click edit on one of these records
4. You are sent to `ravs#edit` with an `:id` matching the record
5. In this view you can update the values of `:col1` and `:col2`
6. You hit the submit button which sends you to `achvrs#update`

Inside your view for `ravs#edit` you can have this. Using `form_for` like this, should work, since `@achvr` is an instance of the `Achvr` model. It would then point to its own controller.

```
    <%= form_for(@achvr, :html => {:class => '_dec'}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :col1 %>
      <%= f.text_field :col2 %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

In your `achvrs#update` action you can then check the `params` hash for its values. The scaffolded update method should however update things correctly. When you update from `ravs#edit`, `params` will only hold values for `:col1` and `:col2`

A final word! This is not a proper way to do this. You might want to have a user model with permissions. Then filter which values can be edited based on those.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Yes, you have my intentions correct, and I figured that in a production environment this would be based on a model and permissions. Will look for and post on that in time. Thanks again.